# How can MySQL UPDATE more rows than specified?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL `UPDATE` statement using the compound primary key (`Key1,Key2`) of a table that looks something like this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = CASE 
WHEN (Key1=389 AND Key2=5594091315209354374) THEN 1320243147187 
WHEN (Key1=397 AND Key2=8686441440518828409) THEN 1320243147562 
WHEN (Key1=389 AND Key2=5717973625907258381) THEN 1320243147182 
.... 
WHEN (Key1=394 AND Key2=5512452777552926025) THEN 1320243147389 END 
WHERE Key2 IN (123782199165241826,5594091315209354374,...,3553840348728167644) 
AND Key1 IN (400,394,391,389,397);
```

I might have, say, 20 or so `WHEN`s in the `CASE` statement.

How might MySQL say this has updated slightly more rows than there are `WHEN`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CASE statement has **nothing** to do with which rows are affected.  It's *entirely* up to your WHERE clause:

> WHERE Key2 IN (123782199165241826,5594091315209354374,...,3553840348728167644) 
>   AND Key1 IN (400,394,391,389,397);

Every row that fits those conditions will be updated. The question, then, is what happens to the rows that don't match a CASE condition?

For this part I'm not 100% sure what MySQL will do, as I'm more of a sql server guy. I suspect, however, that your CASE statement results in NULL, which is then assigned to FieldName. It's also possible that MySQL will decide not to change anything, but I would still expect it to report all the rows that match your WHERE clause as updated.

You should probably have an `ELSE FieldName` at the end of your case statement to be *certain* you get the latter behavior (no change) rather than the former (set to NULL).

Answer (score 1):

I think the real determining factors are the values in your WHERE clause -- do these exactly correspond to the WHEN statements?